# A basic joint density function question

Tags: probability

So I am given a joint density function $f(x,y) = \frac{3}{2}(x^2 + y^2)$ defined for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$, and I am trying to find the density function for $X^\frac{1}{2}$. My plan for doing this was to find the cdf for the function and then derivate this. Doing this gives me, 
$$\int_0^{x^\frac{1}{2}} \int_0^{1} \frac{3}{2}(x^2 + y^2) \,dy\,dx$$which derivating this gives me an answer of $\frac{3}{4}x^\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}x^\frac{-1}{2}$ which does not match the answer that my professor posted. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my approach?

Comment: What is the answer your professor posted?

Comment: $x + 3x^5$ extracharacters

Comment: Instead of starting with $f(x,y)$, try starting with the marginal density function of $x$

Comment: That would just be the inner integral. The inner integral gives me that marginal density function which i then integrated again to find the cdf of $X^\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: The quickest way to fix your approach is that you should replace the $\sqrt x$ in the upper limit of the integral with an $x^2.$ See if you can figure out why. This yields your professor's correct answer. (You got something backwards.)

Comment: Is this because $x$ is ranging from 0 to $y^2$?

Comment: It's cause the CDF of $\sqrt X$ is $P(\sqrt X \le x) = P(X\le x^2).$ (you actually computed the PDF of $X^2.$)

Answer (score 0):

if you integrate f(x,y) = (3/2)(x^2 + y^2)  with respect to y over the support (0,1) you'll get the marginal f(x) = (1/2)x^2 + (1/2)
Say g(x) = X^(1/2)  is the transformation you want
so find g-1(x) = X^2
then f(Y) = f(g-1(x))*(d/dx)(g-1(x))
          = [(3/2)*(x^2)^2 + (1/2)] * [(d/dx)(x^2)]
          = [(3/2)*(x^4) + (1/2)] * [2x]
          =  3x^5 + x